# Bin values into factors

Tags: r

In my data frame, I have a column containing series of location values:

```
DistData$LOC=c(0,0,0,25,25,35,35,45,45,55,55,55,65,65,65,75,75,75,100,100,100,REF1,REF1,REF2,REf3,REF3,REF3)
```

I'd like to bin these into factors, where values less than 50 are "NEAR", 50 or greater are "FAR" and all REF* are "REF".

I've tried converting to as.numeric() then cut():

```
Zone = as.numeric(DistData$LOC)
Zone = cut(Zone, c(0,50,200,NA),labels=c("NEAR","FAR","REF"))
```

And tried a series of ifelse statements:

```
Zone = ifelse(Zone<50,"NEAR", ifelse(Zone>=50,"FAR", ifelse(is.na(Zone)<-"REF")))
```

also toyed with gsub(), lapply() and replace() without success.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: try `as.numeric(as.character(())` instead of just `as.numeric`. You are coercing your factor to the underlying integer value instead of the distance it represents textually.

Comment: What is the meaning of REF?  If it means something like "missing data", I would be inclined to convert REFs to NAs and convert the other values to an *ordered* factor type, since the levels have an inherent order to them (Near < Far), as opposed to an unordered factor (e.g. Red, Blue, Green).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a longer method that produces your desired result:

```
# convert to character vector
temp <- as.character(DistData$LOC)
# fill any refs with "999"
temp[grep("REF", toupper(temp)) ] <- "999"
# use cut to get desired categories
cut(as.numeric(temp), breaks=c(0,50,100, 1000), labels=c("near", "far", "ref"),
    include.lowest=T)
```

This results in

```
[1] near near near near near near near near near far  far  far  far  far  far  far  far  far 
[19] far  far  far  ref  ref  ref  ref  ref  ref 
Levels: near far ref
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @lmo's solution, but here's another using the `bin_data()` function from [mltools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mltools/index.html).

```
library(mltools)

# Build vector of values.  I assume class(DistData$LOC) == "character" in your data.frame
temp <- c(
  "0", "0", "0", "25", "25", "35", "35", "45", "45", "55", "55", 
  "55", "65", "65", "65", "75", "75", "75", "100", "100", "100", 
  "REF1", "REF1", "REF2", "REf3", "REF3", "REF3"
)

# Convert to numeric. REFs (and other non-numeric values will coerce to NA)
temp_numeric <- as.numeric(temp)

# Bin the values using "[left-closed, right-open)" bins
binned_vals <- bin_data(temp_numeric, bins=c(-Inf, 50, Inf), boundaryType = "lcro)")

# Insert a level for REF > all other levels
levels(binned_vals) <- c(levels(binned_vals), "REF")

# Locate REFs and set convert from NA to REF
binned_vals[grep("REF", toupper(temp))] <- "REF"

binned_vals
[1] [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [-Inf, 50) [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf) 
[13] [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  [50, Inf)  REF        REF        REF       
[25] REF        REF        REF       
Levels: [-Inf, 50) < [50, Inf) < REF
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` creates a factor variable but its levels don't contain `NA`.

We can use `addNA` to repair this, and then assign the right labels using `factor`, paying attention not to exclude the NA level we have just created :

```
factor(
  addNA(cut(as.numeric(LOC),c(0,50,200),right = FALSE)),
  labels =  c("NEAR","FAR","REF"),exclude=NULL)
#  [1] NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR NEAR FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  FAR  REF  REF  REF  REF  REF  REF 
# Levels: NEAR FAR REF
```